# How to remove rows with more than one value in a cell in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that looks like below:

```
 receiver_id  sender_id
    a,b,d         c
    a,d           b
    b             a
    a             b
```

I would like to remove rows containing more than one `receiver_id`. So the final data frame should only have row 3 and 4. How should I go about doing that?

Desired output:

```
 receiver_id  sender_id
        b             a
        a             b
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can boolean slice the data frame by looking for a comma, assuming the multiple values are a single string and not a list.

```
df = df[~df.receiver_id.str.contains(',')].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
df.loc[df['receiver_id'].str.count(',').eq(0)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df = df[df['receiver_id'].str.split(',').str.len()<2]
```

If that is already a list in the column you can simplify it to:

```
df = df[df['receiver_id'].str.len()<2]
```